# How can I add multiple string inputs in a for loop to a single variable in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, concatenation

I'm a new coder and started coding in Python at school, but my school program is so slow (and now even slower because of covid-19) that i've kind of fallen down a well... how again do you add a string input to an empty string variable?

Let's say I enter 'frog', 'cow', and 'duck'. This code only returns "duck". What do I change for it to return "frog cow duck"? Thanks :)

Here is what i've tried:

```
for i in range(5):
    word_list = ""
    word = input("Enter a word for the word list: ")
    word_list = word_list + word + ""   

print word_list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are reinitializing word_list inside the for loop, this is a logic error.

Answer (score 0):

```
x1,x2,x3 = input("Enter Name: ").split() #frog cow duck
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. This answer demonstrates a technique, but if you check the code in the question it will result in a different user experience in that it won't ask for five words, and it requires the user to separate the input with spaces, and it won't allow for inputs that need to include spaces.